# Error with the button

Tags: java, android, button

Our button we created stops when we run the app in the emulator. We press the button and then the whole app chrashes. Heres the main activity code with button.

```
Button kontakter;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override 
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     kontakter = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Kontakter);
     kontakter.setOnClickListener(this);}



private void kontakterClick()
{
        startActivity(new Intent ("com.example.kyren.Kontakter"));
}




public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.Kontakter:
        kontakterClick();
        break;

    }

}}
```

Comment: show logcat output...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
 startActivity(new Intent ("com.example.kyren.Kontakter"));
```

use

```
 startActivity(new Intent (<currentclassname>.this,<navigateclass>.class));
```